# Push, Pop, Range in constant time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was asked this in an interview:

Design a data structure that allows all these operations in constant, `O(1)`, time:

- Push an element
- Pop an element
- Range of elements : Find the smallest range of interval of the current elements.
  Eg. Range of `[1, 22, 44, 56, 99, 98, 56]` is `98`.

I designed this using a customized stack with two variables, `max` and `min`, but this doesn't work after Pop'ing a min or max element.

What I tried :

I used a stack with two extra variable max and min:

```
DS 
{
 top, //Top of the Stack 
 min, //Min till now
 max  //Max till now
}

Push(DS, elem)
  Push_Stack(DS.top, elem)
  if elem < DS.min
    DS.min = elem
  if elem > DS.max
    DS.max = elem

Range(DS)
 return DS.max - DS.min

Pop(DS)
  x = Pop_Stack(DS.top)
  if (x == DS.min)
    DS.min = Find_New_Min(DS.top) //This takes linear time using this approach
  if (x == DS.max)
    DS.max = Find_New_Max(DS.top)
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @mohit I think what you've proposed is actualy a possible answer. You just need to update max and min after a push or pop.

Comment: It looks like the general idea is good. Show your code (pseudocode will do). What exactly didn't work?

Comment: There's a problem with `Pop()` needing to find the new minimum or maximum - the way you have it now, `Pop()` isn't an O(1) operation. You can solve this problem by adding information to what goes on the stack - there's no reason that the stack needs to contain only the element being pushed.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Yes that's exactly the problem with my approach. Top is a linked list representation of a `Stack`. Can you be more explicit in what you're proposing?

Comment: @ShashankGupta, Yes, I thought of that. But the question required O(1) insertion and deletion.

Comment: No, this is not how it's done. I'm now supposed to give a subtle and profound hint that will enlighten you and let you discover a path to a solution almost on your own. But you will probably get more than one working solution in a couple of minutes anyway.

Comment: How about maintaining another stack to keep track of min and max in pop and push routine ?

Comment: Biggest range not smallest range?

Comment: @lucian, It was something like smallest range in the integer set, that contained the elements in the data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement a "Stack" that includes a range function and uses three stacks internally.

---

The First internal stack will represent the 'real' stack of things being pushed and popped.

The second internal stack will only be pushed to if the new element is bigger than or equal to what is on top of it.

The third internal stack will only be pushed to if the new element is smaller than or equal to what is on top of it.

---

Now, whenever you need to calculate the range, just peek at the top of the second and third stacks and do some simple math.

Whenever an element needs to be popped off the 'real' stack, check to see if the element is also at the top of each of the other two stacks, if it is, pop it off those stacks as well.

Since you have to pop items off the main stack in the opposite order they came in, you won't ever miss anything in the two other stacks... meaning the top of the second and third internal stacks will always be the max and min.

Comment: The max may become min at some time. Can this take that into account.

Comment: Seems pretty close. What will happen after `push 0; push 100; push 0; push 100; pop; pop`?

Comment: @n.m. After all 4 pushes, the min stack will hold 0, 0 (bottom to top ordering). The max stack will hold 0, 100, 100. After the 2 pops, the min stack will hold 0. The max stack will hold 0, 100.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal It is always the case that min == max if the stack only contains a single distinct value. It is only after 2 distinct values are inserted into the stack that the min stack and max stack begin to diverge.

Comment: Ah OK. It says "bigger or equal", I must have missed the "or equal" part.

Comment: Yes, and actually I think a max can never become min because the ordering shall be preserved while popping the elements.

Comment: Whao, went to dinner after my post... you guys had quite a discussion since then :-D  I'm glad it works tho!

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Bryon Lo answer, but before he posted I [commented same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341955/push-pop-range-in-constant-time#comment28655300_19341955)

Maintain 3 stacks

- S1 your final stacks
- S2 and S3 temporary stacks

Rest is self explanatory

```
  push(T value)
  {
    if (value <= min()) 
    {
        s2.push(value);
    }

    if(value >= max())
    {
        s3.push(value);
    }
    s1.push(value);
  }

 T pop() 
 {
    T value = s1.pop();
    if (value == min()) 
    {
        s2.pop();
    }
    return value;
  }

  T min() 
  {
    if (s2.isEmpty()) 
    {
        return MAX_VALUE;
    } 
    else {
        return s2.peek();
    }
  }

   T max() 
  {
    if (s3.isEmpty()) 
    {
        return MIN_VALUE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return s3.peek();
    }
  }
```

Comment: 5:30:00Z vs 5:29:49Z.  11 Seconds between your comment and my post lol.